# How to prevent double login with one account?

Tags: php

i am working on php language,
i want to ensure that one id(username / account) is not login in more than one computer.
how can it tobe possible?

the logic is like this, if one account login, he/she cannot login in other computer if he/she did not Logout first from his/her first computer.

if we make some "logic" in LOGOUT button, maybe i can handle it, but how if the computer shutted down? the session is deleted, without executing the "logic" in LOGOUT button.

Comment: Already asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727919/how-to-prevent-multiple-logins-in-php-website

Answer (score 1):

Just add some additional field to user DB. On login generate unical id into this field (server-sided), send it to user as cookie, for example. And when user performs some action-attempt, compare his cookie with value from DB.